# iTerm2 settings are reset upon app close

Tags: macos, iterm, themes

If I change a setting within iTerm2, using the Preferences panel ex. under Window i set transparency and blur. This works as long as I do not close iTerm. Once I close the app and reopen, everything is reset to as it were before.

Also the Theme i am using is not showing properly. Some of the colors wont change even if I change to different themes.

I am using oh-my-zsh. as well!

- This problem has persisted in all versions of OS X I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

When I transferred my iTerm2 profiles over from Mavericks to Yosemite I ran into the same problem. I found that apple caches application preferences so after you make the changes try running `sudo killall cfprefsd` to clear to preference cache. This seemed to do the trick for me.